Is there a method to increase box height in CSS grid without affecting other boxes in the row?
I'm currently working on designing a layout similar to the one attached in the screenshot To achieve this, I've opted for CSS Grid for its ease of use and responsiveness.
However, I've encountered a challenge. I want each box to dynamically adjust its height based on its content, without affecting the heights of other boxes in the same row. Currently, when one box increases in height due to its content, it affects the heights of all other boxes in the row.
Is there a way to achieve the desired behavior without compromising the responsiveness of the layout? If not with CSS Grid, would you recommend a different approach that better suits my requirements?


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  padding: 5%;
}

.parent-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2rem;
}

.box {
  background-color: aqua;
  min-height: 300px;
}
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="box">**Lorem ipsum 200**
  </div>
  <div class="box">Item 2</div>
  <div class="box">Item 3</div>
  <div class="box">Item 4</div>
  <div class="box">Item 5</div>
  <div class="box">Item 6</div>
  <div class="box">Item 7</div>
  <div class="box">Item 8</div>
  <div class="box">Item 9</div>
  <div class="box">Item 10</div>
  <div class="box">Item 11</div>
  <div class="box">Item 12</div>
  <div class="box">Item 13</div>
  <div class="box">Item 14</div>
  <div class="box">Item 15</div>
  <div class="box">Item 16</div>
  <div class="box">Item 17</div>
  <div class="box">Item 18</div>
  <div class="box">Item 19</div>
  <div class="box">Item 20</div>
</div>




overflow: hidden I guess?

You haven't really made it clear what you want to see. Do you want the boxes to stack tightly in their columns, or do you want the rows still to line up? (You didn't post the screenshot.)

There is no attached screenshot to see the desired output. Do you want the rows to line up and leave blank space or is it suppose to tile filling all blanks?

You can easily do this. You should use align-items on the .parent-container element, then the box height will increase dynamically based on your content's height.


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    padding: 5%;
}

.parent-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 2rem;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.box {
    background-color: aqua;
    min-height: 200px; 
}
<div class="parent-container">
        <div class="box">**Lorem ipsum 200** it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
        </div>
        <div class="box">Item 2</div>
        <div class="box">Item 3</div>
        <div class="box">Item 4</div>
        <div class="box">Item 5</div>
        <div class="box">Item 6</div>
        <div class="box">Item 7</div>
        <div class="box">Item 8</div>
        <div class="box">Item 9</div>
        <div class="box">Item 10</div>
        <div class="box">Item 11</div>
        <div class="box">Item 12</div>
        <div class="box">Item 13</div>
        <div class="box">Item 14</div>
        <div class="box">Item 15</div>
        <div class="box">Item 16</div>
        <div class="box">Item 17</div>
        <div class="box">Item 18</div>
        <div class="box">Item 19</div>
        <div class="box">Item 20</div>
    </div>



